# The mute control in ubuntu is F1 but when i play Pc building simulator there is also an F1 control

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, games, mute

So i can not use a control in the game which is F1 because if i press it in the game it just mutes the volume in ubuntu.

I am running ubuntu 20.04/

Comment: Change another key than F1 as a replacement for that key in the gamecontrols and that should be it.

Comment: I don't think the mute control in Ubuntu is F1, at least not by default. You can check if any keyboard shortcut is mapped to F1 by going to `Settings -> Keyboard -> View and Customise Shortcuts`. But it's more likely your laptop/PC special function keys setup with F1 as mute. What make/model is your system/keyboard. What does the F1 key show on it? Usually you press F1 for function key and Fn-F1 for the special operation. But on some PC's this is swapped around. F1 will do the special operation and Fn-F1 will do the function key. Sometimes there is a BIOS setting to choose which way.

Comment: So my keyboard is a lenovo keyboard and on the F1 keycap its a speaker with a cross on it.

Comment: You might need to disable the Hot Key mode in your BIOS https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht103044-how-to-use-the-function-keys-without-pressing-fn-in-windows-8110 so that the system will only do that mute when you press Fn+F1.  Sounds like the Hot Key mode is enabled so that when you press F1 by itself it mutes without pressing the Fn key as well.

Comment: Ok thank u very much

Comment: i dont have a FN key on my keyboard

Comment: So i am using a lenovo keyboard on a PC

Comment: Have you checked with Lenovo support themselves about that keyboard?